# Create hidden post via facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Something that is probably a very quick question. I would like to create a new post on a facebook page via the graph API that has a *timeline_visibility* of *hidden* at the time of posting.

Currently my work around is:

1. Create the post.
2. Hide the post.

Via these steps the post does however momentarily appear on the page when the process is between step 1 and 2. I would like to know if it's possible to combine step 1 and 2? The API documentation in this area has not given me any working solutions yet. So far I have tried:

1. Creating the post with the timeline_visibility param (no effect).
2. Creating an unpublished post and then attempting to apply the timeline_visibility param to that (resulted in error).

Comment: Where did you see the 'timeline_visibility' param? Would a scheduled post for pages work for your use case?

Comment: timeline_visibility is mentioned elsewhere in the graph documentation regarding hidden posts. Thanks for the reply but unfortunately scheduled posts are not suitable in this use case.

Comment: Can you point me to the graph docs mentioning 'timeline_visibility'?